# Docker-compose build blocked after saying "Building <service>"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I needed to rebuild a container and since then nothing works as expected:

```
docker-compose build 
Building web
```

The whole thing remains blocked there, while the same config will work locally. Here's what I have:

```
docker-compose version 1.11.0, build 6de1806
docker-py version: 2.0.2
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

On `Ubuntu 16.04`.

And the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: npm start
  volumes:
    - .:/app
    - /app/node_modules
  ports:
    - "3030:3030"
```

What can the mistake be? I'm sure it is a small tiny detail...
Or how can I debug this?

I tried to uninstall/reinstall everything, even removed `/var/lib/docker` content...

---

EDIT:

If I run the command with the `--verbose` flag, I get:

```
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/root/.docker/config.json', '/root/.dockercfg']
docker.auth.find_config_file: No config file found
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.11.0, build 6de1806
docker-py version: 2.0.2
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localunixsocket
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: KernelVersion=4.4.0-75-generic, Arch=amd64, BuildTime=2017-05-04T22:10:54.638119411+00:00, ApiVersion=1.29, Version=17.05.0-ce, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=89658be, Os=linux, GoVersion=go1.7.5
compose.service.build: Building web
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (pull=False, stream=True, nocache=False, tag=u'api_web', buildargs=None, rm=True, forcerm=False, path='/var/www/api', dockerfile=None)
```

And if I try to build without compose, it works:

```
docker build .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!!

By running `docker build .`, I got `Sending build context to Docker daemon  125.2MB` but on my server, the size was increasing up to several `GB`...

I realized my folder content was huge because the server job is to build wav files, and I did not clean it recently.

So the problem was that the `Sending build context to Docker daemon` was muted in `docker-compose` ... and that I should have managed temporary files differently! :)

Comment: You can avoid sending those files to context using a .dockerignore file

Comment: always put all your stuff in a specific directory, where you will have your Dockerfile and the needed files, nothing more